# Is my wireless router's Mac address revealed to the website?

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, mac-address

I know a computer's MAC address is hidden from the website from the earlier post, but what about Mac address of wireless Router?

Answer (score 0):

### As far as networking itself is concerned...

As long as your connection to a certain website more distant than one hop, your MAC address is not given to the website.

According to English Wikipedia, "[Address Resolution Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol)":

> The Address Resolution Protocol is a request-response protocol whose messages are encapsulated by a link layer protocol. It is communicated within the boundaries of a single network, never routed across internetworking nodes. This property places ARP into the link layer of the Internet protocol suite.
>
> — Braden, R. (October 1989). "[RFC 1122 - Requirements for Internet Hosts -- Communication Layers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122)". *ietf.org*. Internet Engineering Task Force.

And there is a reason too: Beyond the network boundaries, the duty of finding the target computer is with the gateway computer. (A router.) So, the engineers didn't trouble themselves adding unnecessary (and potentially privacy-violating) data to the packet.

### ... but is networking the only thing concerned here?

Web browsers can run web apps on your local computers. As of now, these web apps, written in JavaScript, have no way of querying your computer's MAC address. But what about plug-ins, add-ons, and out-of-browser apps? They have access to a much broader API and discovering your MAC address is definitely possible for them. Then, it is only the matter of transmitting it online.

Still, it is quite an ordeal for a website to find the MAC address of your computer in this fashion, and associating it with you. Doing something useful (for itself, not you) with it, is another story entirely. People keep selling their computers all the times and use shared access points. One could clearly see that there is no point in using this tactic as a digital fingerprinting mean, because the tactic itself require fingerprinting in advance.